# Julia function with different parameter subtypes

Tags: function, types, julia

In Julia I can define a function that accepts all subtypes of `Type` by doing

```
function foo{T<:Type}(bar::T, arg::T) end
```

But this imposes that `bar` and `arg` be the same subtype of `Type`. Is there a shorthand to define a function that accepts different subtypes of `Type` for `bar` and `arg`? I know I can do

```
function foo{T<:Type, S<:Type}(bar::T, arg::S) end
```

But for a function with several parameters, it becomes quite cumbersome.

Comment: just to mention, if the type of `bar` or `arg` is not parametric, there is not need to use parametric methods. e.g. `function foo{T<:Integer}(bar::Vector{T}, arg::Number) `

Comment: @GnimucK. I know, but they are all arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the type used on the left hand side of `T<:Type` is an abstract type, then the function argument(s) that are declared to be of type `T` will accept all things that belong to that abstraction, including things that belong to a subordinate (inheriting) abstraction.

For most purposes, these things are realizations of a concrete type, instantiations of the type.  A concrete types may have an abstract type as its supertype, and that abstract type may have a another, more abstract type as its supertype, and so on.  `Any` is the most super supertype, root of the abstract type tree.

In the example

```
 function foo{T<:Type}(bar::T, arg::T) ... end
```

At each invocation of `foo`, `T` takes on exactly one of the subtypes of `Type` or remains `Type` itself.  That is why `bar` and `arg` must share the same specific type for this version of `foo` to be matched and called.  And it explains why the next example matches and is called

```
 function foo{T<:Type, U<:Type}(bar::T, arg::U) ... end
```

when `foo` and `bar` are each subtypes of `Type` but are realizations of two distinct concrete types (e.g. `Int32` and `Int64` share the abstract supertype `Integer`).

There is no general shorthand for using parameters that you intend to accept different sorts of things; that the different sorts share a common abstract type is useful information and allows you to define both the first and the second ways to call `foo`.  That flexible way of managing algorithmic specification often simplifies implementation.  That is some of the strength that Julia's multidispatch offers.

There are situations where the use of `typealias` may simplify writing a function signature.  `typealias` works well to selectively dispatch using nonoverlapping collections of subtypes that share a supertype.

```
typealias FastInt Union{ Int32, Int64 }  # division is fast
typealias SlowInt Union{ Int8, Int128 }  # slightly slower

foo{T<:Integer}(a::T, b::T) ... end; # default/fallback 
foo{T<:FastInt}(a::T, b::T) ... end; # specialized for fast types
foo{T<:SlowInt}(a::T, b::T) ... end; # specialized for slow types
```

```

Comment: So there's no shorthand. Sad. I'm really writing `function foo{T<:Type}(bar::AbstractArray{T}, arg::AbstractArray{T}) end`. Should've specified. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply write this as

```
function foo(bar::MyType, arg::MyType)
    ...
end
```

Inside the function, if you need the concrete types, use `typeof(bar)` and `typeof(arg)`. These are constants and so will not affect performance.

Of course I'm assuming you mean `Type` as some user-defined type, and not the built-in `Type` type.

Even if the arguments are arrays, the function need not be written parametrically. It is perfectly OK to do

```
function foo(bar::AbstractArray, arg::AbstractArray)
    ...
end
```

and inside the function use `eltype(bar)` and `eltype(arg)` if necessary. However, I would personally use the parametric form if the `eltype`s are required.

Comment: I should've been more specific, but I'm really writing `function foo{T<:Type}(bar::AbstractArray{T}, arg::AbstractArray{T}) end`

Comment: @Mauricio: Yes, then I prefer the parametric approach.

Comment: Well, I thought the point was to avoid in-function checks. Besides, I'm not sure how to specify dimension without specifying type, or am I missing something obvious there?

Comment: You can specify dimension by using a `typealias`.

Comment: But as I said in my answer, I prefer the parametric form `{T<:Type,U<:Type}` in these situations.